# Freemarker Checkboxes input in Spring form

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, freemarker

I have an HTML form bound to a Spring model to take in user data and add it to a database. This works fine. I have used Spring Freemarker macros for the fields to take input and validate before sending, e.g.

```
<@spring.formInput path="myForm.username"/>
<@spring.showErrors ", "/>
```

This also works fine for text input. What is causing me problems is rendering multiple checkboxes with the Spring macro. My original HTML was:

```
<input name="roleList" type="checkbox" value="1"/>Adminstrator
<input name="roleList" type="checkbox" value="2"/>Developer
<input name="roleList" type="checkbox" value="3"/>Customer
```

I created a Java `Map<String, String>` of this information with the keys as "1", "2", "3" in my controller method and added it to the model, then replaced the HTML with this macro in my ftl template:

```
<@spring.formCheckboxes path="quickForm.roleList" options="${roleMap}" separator="<br>"/>
```

But I get an error

```
Expecting a string, date or number here, Expression roleMap is instead a freemarker.template.SimpleHash
```

Why would it give that message if it requires a Map? (as in the Spring Docs for FreeMarker macros) Can anyone explain how I should be providing the checkbox data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally worked this out, so for anyone who's interested: it wasn't as straightforward as just creating a HashMap of values and adding them with `model.addAttribute("roleMap", myHash)` - I had to create a service class to do this  instead: it retrieved my list of roles from a database table and then converted them into a `HashMap<String, String>`. I then called this in my controller method, added it to my model (called "roleMap" here) and used it within my FreeMarker template *without* the usual formatting, like this:

```
<@spring.formCheckboxes path="quickForm.roleList" options=roleMap separator="<br>"/>
```

Having the data converted in a service method was key for Spring to use it as checkbox options.

Comment: Just to mention that I think the diagnosis of the actual problem here is incorrect. I have done the same thing you describe, with creating the map in my controller and adding them to the model, and it works fine, without a complicated Service in the middle. My guess is the key here was changing from `options=${roleMap}` to `options=roleMap`